# HTMLUnit add request android

Tags: android, kotlin, htmlunit

I try to use HTMLUnit for parsing.
I create the web client:

```
 val webClient = WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX);
  webClient.addRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
  webClient.addRequestHeader(
            "User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        )
        
        webClient.removeRequestHeader("Sec-Fetch-Mode")
        webClient.removeRequestHeader("Sec-Fetch-User")
        webClient.removeRequestHeader("Sec-Fetch-Site")
        webClient.removeRequestHeader("Sec-Fetch-Dest")
        webClient.removeRequestHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=1")
        webClient.addRequestHeader("TEST HEADER", "application/json")
        return webClient;
```

I write to remove several headers and to add headers, but when I reading request headers from responce I dont recive my headers. Why?
I recive:

```
{Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8, X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest, Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=1, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36, Sec-Fetch-Dest=document, Sec-Fetch-Site=same-origin, Sec-Fetch-User=?1, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.5, Sec-Fetch-Mode=navigate}
```

Answer (score 0):

The jdoc is not really clear about this - in fact the WebClient has a list of additional request headers always added to the request. You can use this list to add more headers if you like. And the two methods addRequestHeader() and removeRequestHeader() are there to maintain this list.

But

- this list is usually empty
- all the headers sent by the browser in default case are added to the request after the list of (additional) headers is processed.

This means you can't remove some standard header from the request using this API.